# How to display for static block pages for magento1.9.0.1?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, static-block

i created staticblock pages in admin panel(magento ver1.9.0.1),but while creating pages the storeview tab is missing..so,i'm unable to create a layout for my staticblock pages.please check the image below:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have single store, then it will not asking for store view.
which error message you got while saving static blocks ?

Answer :
1. Add CMS Block with Banner
    - http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2010900/2819f42368db4893663d47c2a54d9b51

2. Add layout update for banner

   - Find home page in CMS pages Section
   - "Design" Tab
   - Layout Update XML

         
             banner-static-block-identifier
   - Save It.
3. {{THEME PATH}}/template/page/html/header.phtml

   - Add this line where you want.

     getChildHtml('banner-static-block-identifier') ?>

Comment: thank you @prathmeshb1 ya i have only one store..but how i will add page layout (for example:i want to add banner images at headertop in homepage,how can i will add banner images)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one website with single store or storeview then it will not be display.
Please first create at least one extra store.